# Trying to persist a new (unmanaged) entity with auto generated ID causes error

Tags: java, jpa, derby

I have a `MyEntity` class with several columns one of which is an auto increment id. `MyEntity` looks like the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

When I create a new `MyEntity` and set all other columns (I do not set the id column), and then call `persist`:

```
MyEntity mn = new MyEntity("val1", "val2");
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(mn);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

the following error occurs:

> Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET
>   SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.

I tried to change the strategy of `@GeneratedValue` with no avail. There are plenty of similar issues online, but with no clear solution what to do in this case.

Do I need to assign a certain value to the `id` column in my new unmanaged entity? Do I need to setup specific values in the table where the `id` column is (I only set that it's a primary key)?

Comment: paste pesrsistence.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use identity for generating ID by DB:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Do not add optional=false, nullable=false. Primary key will be never null in RDBS.

Comment: This does work and I did use it beforehand. I believe the problem was in my table and the way I created my primary key. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what went wrong, but I think "INCREMENT BY 1" in Add Column of the Netbeans derby plugin solved the issue.

Comment: Oh, and an important thing I forgot to mention. If you automatically generate classes from a database in Netbeans, all newly created classes will require in their constructors from the user to set an ID. I was passing 0 and other values in hope they'll be ignored, but finally removed ID from the constructor and added the IDENTITY strategy.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO states that the persistence provider will choose the most appropriate solution.

If you are using Hibernate, have you correctly set the dialect explicitly? Oftentimes I've seen Hibernate try to guess the correct dialect but get it wrong. This can cause a domino effect of the AUTO strategy being poorly chosen.